# SwiftUI Showing Specific Landmarks on Opening the map

Tags: swift, swiftui, location, mapkit

I was wondering to see if there is a way to show the nearest specific landmarks[ie railway stations] just to see where the user can go to? I am trying to also show the point to point of landmarks but should revolve first around the user. top 3 nearest landmarks should do, please any help or resources?

```html
import MapKit
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct SearchView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Home()
    }
}

struct SearchView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SearchView()
    }
}


struct Home: View  {
    @State var map = MKMapView()
    @State var manager = CLLocationManager()
    @State var alert = false
    @State var source : CLLocationCoordinate2D!
    @State var destination : CLLocationCoordinate2D!
    
    var body: some View{
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom){
            VStack(spacing:0){
                HStack{
                    Text("Station Search").font(.title)
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding()
                .padding(.top, UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.top).background(Color.white)
                
                MapView(map: self.$map, manager: self.$manager, alert:
                            self.$alert, source: self.$source,
                        destination: self.$destination)
                    .onAppear {
                        self.manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
                    }
            }
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .alert(isPresented: self.$alert) { () -> Alert in
            
            Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text("Please Enable Location In Setting !!!"), dismissButton: .destructive(Text("Ok")))
        }
    }
}

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
        @Binding var map: MKMapView
        @Binding var manager : CLLocationManager
        @Binding var alert : Bool
        @Binding var source : CLLocationCoordinate2D!
        @Binding var destination : CLLocationCoordinate2D!
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return MapView.Coordinator(parent1: self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        map.delegate = context.coordinator
        manager.delegate = context.coordinator
        map.showsUserLocation = true
        return map
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context){
        
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
        
        var parent : MapView
        
        init(parent1 : MapView) {
            parent =  parent1
        }
        
        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
            if status == .denied {
                self.parent.alert.toggle()
                
            }
            else{
                self.parent.manager.startUpdatingLocation()
            }
        }
        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[CLLocation]) {
            
            let region =  MKCoordinateRegion(center: locations.last!.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 1000, longitudinalMeters: 1000)
            self.parent.source = locations.last!.coordinate
            
            self.parent.map.region = region
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are looking to add points of interest, you have to look them up first. See [Searching for Nearby Points of Interest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/searching_for_nearby_points_of_interest). If you want to show a hybrid or satellite view, you need to set `map.mapType = .hybrid` or `. satellite` in your makeUIView.

Comment: Yeah but it doesn't seem to show anything about automatically showing places of interest/landmarks as soon as the map is open

Comment: You need to add them yourself as annotations to the map.